# Get actual width of column in listview when autosize is on

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, autosize

I set up a width of a column to "-2" according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.columnheader.width%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), which actually autosizes both by content and header.

> To autosize to the width of the column heading, set the Width property to -2

The next thing I want to do is to set up the last column to fill the listview. I'm doing it this way (simplified):

```
myListView.Columns[lastColumnIndex].Width
    += myListView.Width - myListView.Columns.Cast<ColumnHeader>().Sum(column => column.Width);
```

But the width of columns is... "-2".

How can I get the actual width?

Comment: I don't know why you are getting the actual width as 2 in runtime. I tested to make sure and I get the actual width. Did you try to debug and check?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the issue was about setting -2 dynamically. My code looked like:

```
private void Resize()
{   
myListView.Columns[0].Width = -2;            
myListView.Columns[1].Width = -2;

myListView.Columns[2].Width += myListView.Width 
                               - myListView.Columns.Cast<ColumnHeader>().Sum(column => column.Width)
                               - (myListView.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.Fixed3D ? 4 : 2)
                               - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
}
```

And the solution was to add one line:

```
private void Resize()
{   
myListView.Columns[0].Width = -2;            
myListView.Columns[1].Width = -2;
myListView.Columns[2].AutoResize(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.None); // This one

myListView.Columns[2].Width += myListView.Width 
                               - myListView.Columns.Cast<ColumnHeader>().Sum(column => column.Width)
                               - (myListView.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.Fixed3D ? 4 : 2)
                               - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
}
```